# ReactJS - Unit Test does not simulates click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Being java developer and new to react I am stuck with unit test:

```
import React from 'react';   
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import SurveyEditor from './EditorEditor';
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('creates new section upon fucntion call', () => {
    //  editor itsels if root
    const editor = TestRenderer.create(<Editor/>).root;

    const button = editor .findByProps({ id: 'createNew'});
    expect(button).toBeDefined();

    ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(button);


    expect(editor .instance.state.sections.length).toBe(1);
}
```

It renders a component, button is found as expected  - but  simulated click is not dispatched ( code itself works ok,   I verfified it )  -   aparently i miss something obvious  nd simple.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a stub for the `onClick` event on your button and then assert that the stub was called. For more info check out the readme file at https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-test-renderer

Comment: my perception from the documentation was that Simulate.click  would just trigger whatever callbacks were in place -  or does jest stub out methods automagcally?

Comment: asserting that stub was called is not my intention.  I would  like to assert that proper object function as called and produced desired result.

Comment: I am unsure how to achieve what you are aiming for but you may want to consider using the enzyme library in your test to render your component, you will then be able to assert that your component state has changed to the correct value after simulating your button click.